# Does Zinsser BIN need to "fully" cure before painting?

Tags: painting, primer

I have two coats of Zinsser BIN primer drying on top of a layer of cured vinyl spackle (MH Ready Patch). How long must I wait before painting? The BIN label says it can be "**TOP**coated" in 45 minutes, but the TDS says it can be "**RE**coated" in 45 min (I waited at least that long between the coats). The TDS also says, "The primer film develops full adhesion and hardness after it cures in 1 to 3 days." Do I need to wait 1-3 days for best results? Or even longer -- I've seen cure times of up to 7 days mentioned elsewhere. Or, will it continue to cure normally even if I paint it now? At this point it's been drying for about 24 hours. I'll be painting with Benjamin Moore Advantage. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can paint now. There's a difference between *drying* and *curing*. The primer develops full hardness and adhesion with *curing*, but the 45 minutes is its *drying* time. Just don't drag heavy furniture across it or stuff like that until the *curing* time has elapsed. It can debond or scratch relatively easily before it has fully cured.